# Aluminum Foil Folds and Cut

Tags: geometry, dissection, paper-folding

[image]

Your task is to convert a diamond shape monomino that is made from aluminum foil into an x-shape pentomino (see figures). You may fold the monomino and make one straight cut with a pair of scissors. After the cut, you will unfold the foil and align the separate pieces. The alignment should produce the X-shape shown above, using all pieces of the original monomino. How can this be done without any additional tools?

Note: No overlapping and pieces can be flipped but not need to be attached or joined.

Comment: Should the cut-off pieces or the remaining foil be an X after the cut?

Comment: @bobble -All the foil pieces including remaining piece or pieces

Comment: How? Are the pieces placed next to each other? On top of each other? How are they attached? (This should all be added to the question as clarifications)

Comment: [This earlier question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73579/20814) brings you more than halfway to the answer, as it shows the dissection you are aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution, and on request an asymmetric solution:

> Symmetric:
>  Cut A=B=C=D to X after folding the blue dotted line in picture 2.
>  Pieces 1 to 4 are now cut off, and can be moved to make the cross.
>  note: The initial folds are the 1/4 - 3/4 lines
>  Asymmetric:
>  Fold A to X3, D to X1, B to X4
>  ('line' to cut is now X1,X2,X3)
>  Fold X1X2 to X3X4 and then p to q
>  cut X4 to X3  [[image]

Comment: Nice.can you do without similar pieces?